# Determine if attribute given in JSON is an array

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to iterate through the parameters in JSON and i want to identify all the types that i'm getting.

Here i'm getting JSON from input and determining that it's valid JSON, and calling out recursive array in order to iterate over each attribute.

```
    $textAreaValue = $_POST['textAreaInput'];
    $textAreaValue = preg_replace('/\s+/S', "", $textAreaValue);
    $decodedJson = json_decode($textAreaValue,true);
    switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            $success = array_walk_recursive($decodedJson, "jsonValidator");
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo json_encode(' - Syntax error, malformed JSON');
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
        break;
        default:
            echo ' - Unknown error';
        break;
    }
```

This function is meant to validate attributes with their respective types:

```
function jsonValidator($value,$key){
    if ($key == "username"){
        if (gettype($value) != string){
            echo json_encode("ERR002 - Not allowed type for attribute: ".$key.", expected: String");
        }
    }
    else if ($key == "isRealUser"){
        if (gettype($value) != boolean){
            echo json_encode("ERR002 - Not allowed type for attribute: ".$key.", expected: Boolean");
        }
    }
    else if ($key == "availablePlatforms"){
        echo json_encode(is_null($value));
    }
    else if ($key == "mobile"){
        echo json_encode(is_null($value));
    }
    else if ($key == "desktop"){
        echo json_encode(is_null($value));
    }
    else if ($key == "availableBalances"){
        if (gettype($value) != object){
            echo json_encode("ERR002 - Not allowed type for attribute: ".$key.", expected: Object");
        }
    }
    else if ($key == "currency"){
        if (gettype($value) != string){
            echo json_encode("ERR002 - Not allowed type for attribute: ".$key.", expected: String");
        }
    }
    else if ($key == "amount"){
        if (gettype($value) != integer){
            echo json_encode("ERR002 - Not allowed type for attribute: ".$key.", expected: Integer");
        }
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode("ERR001 - Unknown attribute");
    }
}
```

I can clearly identify objects, but cannot identify arrays, ajax response will be empty. What might be wrong here?

Demo ajax:

```
{
"demoArray":[]
}
```

Putting values in there will just recursively return value, but i'd like to determine that it's an array.

Edit:

I tested with PHPTester, whenever i give something else as a value to `availablePlatforms` instead of an array, i get echoed `here`. Otherwise, it wouldn't echo anything:

```
$decodedJson = json_decode('{"availablePlatforms": "asd"}',true);
$success = array_walk_recursive($decodedJson, "jsonValidator");
function jsonValidator($value,$key){
    if ($key == "username"){
        if (gettype($value) != string){
            echo json_encode("ERR002 - Not allowed type for attribute: ".$key.", expected: String");
        }
    }
    else if ($key == "isRealUser"){
        if (gettype($value) != boolean){
            echo json_encode("ERR002 - Not allowed type for attribute: ".$key.", expected: Boolean");
        }
    }
    else if ($key == "availablePlatforms"){
        echo "here";
    }
    else if ($key == "mobile"){
        echo json_encode(is_null($value));
    }
    else if ($key == "desktop"){
        echo json_encode(is_null($value));
    }
    else if ($key == "availableBalances"){
        if (gettype($value) != object){
            echo json_encode("ERR002 - Not allowed type for attribute: ".$key.", expected: Object");
        }
    }
    else if ($key == "currency"){
        if (gettype($value) != string){
            echo json_encode("ERR002 - Not allowed type for attribute: ".$key.", expected: String");
        }
    }
    else if ($key == "amount"){
        if (gettype($value) != integer){
            echo json_encode("ERR002 - Not allowed type for attribute: ".$key.", expected: Integer");
        }
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode("ERR001 - Unknown attribute");
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be worth looking into [JSON schema](https://json-schema.org/) and using a validator that works with JSON schemas (schemata?) . Quick google search reveals https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're trying to reimplement [`json_last_error_msg`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-last-error-msg.php%60).

Without the `$assoc` argument to `true` PHP will decode JSON objects as instances of `stdClass`, not arrays.

You're checking twice for object and you forgot quotes around.

As @apokryfos says you should leverage existing solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I changed it to `true`, but i'm still having difficulties with parsing it. Updated code. It gets the value 'availablePlatforms' but breaks with array due to some reason.